What is the Threads::Threads library which CMake thinks Gtest need?
I am trying to install and run Gtest on C++ applications on Arch Linux.
CMake tries to link to a library Threads::Threads, which doesn't exist and isn't actually needed.
I want to know what that library is, where do I find it? and why it is included?.
It works fine if I just install gtest and compile and link manually: g++ test.cpp -lgtest -o runTests, (or use a manually created makefile).
But when using CMake to do the same thing (steps below), it seems to require a library "Thread::Thread" which does not appear to exist on my computer (error messages below).
I am not the first to get this error, and an easy workaround is to manually delete the flag -lThreads::Threads in the file build/CMakeFiles/runTests.dir/link.txt, between steps 4 and 5.
But I want to know what this missing library is, is there some package with Threads::Threads I should just install? and why is it required when it is evidently not needed?
Reproducing the error (and workaround)
My procedure is as follows:

(Optionally run full system upgrade) Installed/updated CMake and gtest packages

Go to /usr/src/gtest and run:
sudo cmake CMakeLists.txt
sudo make
sudo cp lib/*.a /usr/lib


Make a directory with two files: test.cpp and whattotest.cpp. In my case I simply test a number echo:
// whattotest.cpp
double Echo(const double a) {
    return a;
}

// tests.cpp
#include "whattotest.cpp"
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(echo, PositiveNos) {
    ASSERT_EQ( 1.5  ,Echo( 1.5) );
    ASSERT_EQ( 0.0  ,Echo( 0.0) );
    ASSERT_EQ( 5.433,Echo( 5.433) );
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}


Create CMakeList.txt with:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

# Locate GTest
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Link runTests with what we want to test and the GTest and pthread library
add_executable(runTests tests.cpp)
target_link_libraries(runTests ${GTEST_LIBRARIES} pthread )


Run cmake -Bbuild resulting warning (among normal output):
  The link interface of target "GTest::gtest" contains:

    Threads::Threads

  but the target was not found.  Possible reasons include:

    * There is a typo in the target name.
    * A find_package call is missing for an IMPORTED target.
    * An ALIAS target is missing. 


Optional workaround open the file build/CMakeFiles/runTests.dir/link.txt and delete -lThreads::Threads:
/usr/bin/c++ -rdynamic CMakeFiles/runTests.dir/tests.cpp.o -o runTests  /usr/lib/libgtest.so.1.14.0 -lpthread -lThreads::Threads


Run cmake --build build; if the workaround above was skipped the following error happens:
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/runTests.dir/tests.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable runTests
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lThreads::Threads: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/runTests.dir/build.make:98: runTests] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/runTests.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2



If the workaround was applied everything works

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6) requests CMake which is toooo old, and lacks for many things. Try to require, say, version 3.5. Or, better, just specify the version of your CMake.

@Tsyvarev Thanks, that actually did the trick, I did not notice the guide I was using to set up CmakeList.txt was from 2012

The warning about missed target Threads::Threads is the key: with correct CMake configuration a "namespaced" name like foo::bar always denotes the IMPORTED or ALIAS target. If such target is missed, then configuration is wrong, and attempt to build such project has a little sense.
Particular target Threads::Threads is created by the module FindThreads.cmake shipped with CMake. That is, the warning about missed that target usually signals about missed call to find_package(Threads).

When experiment with old CMake versions note, that IMPORTED targets become widely spread only since CMake 3.0. In particular, the target Threads::Threads is created by FindThreads.cmake module only since CMake 3.1 (this is explicitly noted in the documentation for that module).
